# Match first group, second group or both in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
   (electric|acoustic) (guitar|drums)
```

What I need is to match:

```
    electric guitar
    electric drums
    acoustic guitar
    acoustic drums
    electric 
    acoustic
    guitar 
    drums
```

I tried using the ? after both groups, but then it matched everything. Thanks!

Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var s = "electric drums";

 if(s.match('^(?:electric()|acoustic())? ?(?:guitar()|drums())?(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)$')){
    document.write("match");
 } else {
    document.write("no match"); // returns this
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lookahead based regex like this:

```
(?=.*?(?:electric|acoustic|guitar|drums))^(?:electric|acoustic|) ?(?:guitar|drums|)$
```

[**Live Demo**](http://www.rubular.com/r/egHxmYpJ61)

Comment: using match function it matches 'electric randomword'

Comment: Pls check the edited answer or see live demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/egHxmYpJ61 I added anchors `^` and `$` to disallow text like `'electric randomword'`.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to spell it out:

```
^((electric|acoustic) (guitar|drums)|(electric|acoustic|guitar|drums))$
```

or (because you don't need the capturing parentheses)

```
^(?:(?:electric|acoustic) (?:guitar|drums)|(?:electric|acoustic|guitar|drums))$
```

You can also use a trick if you don't like to repeat yourself:

```
^(?:electric()|acoustic())? ?(?:guitar()|drums())?(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)$
```

The `(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)` makes sure that at least one of the previous empty capturing groups (`()`) participated in the match.

Comment: this matches electric randomword

Comment: That depends on how you do the matching; I have added anchors to make that explicit.